# Java EE: Communication between few servers

Tags: web-services, soap, jakarta-ee, jms, distributed-computing

I need a system in which I can send SOAP request to 1 server from a few and then if server has this service it calls and returns value to client.
If not it passes the request to next server on his "list of neighbors". Request is passed until some server has needed service (or not, so we return error result).

My question is. What will be the best way to communicate between those servers. SOAP? Message Driven?
It will be great If it could work without central server. If I will use MD, should not all servers use common JMS on some central server?

Is it possible to send MD to specific server on given address?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) or [Spring Remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html)